# WEKA SMOreg classifier significance testing

Tags: weka, svm, confidence-interval, cross-validation, significance

I am using the SMOreg classifier in WEKA to determine if there is a predictive relationship between one variable and several other variables.  I am using 10-fold cross-validation to get my results.  My teacher wants me to find the confidence of my findings, but this confuses me because I didn't think that this was possible.  How does one test for significance using the SMOreg classifier in WEKA?